# SurveyJS async onValueChanging handler

Tags: surveyjs

I'm trying to find a way to build a handler to validate the new value by capturing user input through a dialog. I guess it's not what `onValueChanging` expecting, as the handler wants `options.value = options.oldValue` insight its body, if I need to reject the change.

If I try to save `options` for later reassignment, it doesn't work. I wonder if anybody tried to do something similar, to make the handler asynchronous-like.

Thanks in advance

Comment: SurveyJS doesn't support async onValueChanging handler

Comment: thank you @TSV, have figured that, still good to know!